# How to repeat text in a column while aligning data with other columns

Tags: python-3.x, list, dataframe

How can I align append item to other columns in a dataframe? I created a list of items to append to the dataframe but I want a repeated text in a column. I'm not sure how can I do that?

```
  reg = ['AUTO'] 
  region = []

 for item in reg:
 region.join(item)
  print(region)

 df = pd.DataFrame({'item': region})
 df3 = df_G.append(df, ignore_index=True)
 
 Current output:
    Gender  a          b        c     d         item
 0  Male    38       63.37     36   60.42        AUTO
 1  Female  22       36.63     24   39.58        NaN
 

Expected Output:
    Gender  a          b        c     d         item
 0  Male    38       63.37     36   60.42        AUTO
 1  Female  22       36.63     24   39.58        AUTO
```